# Start a command line including arguments from C#

Tags: c#, process

I need to start a complete command line like "app.exe /arg1:1 /arg2:true" from my C# app.

Process.Start and ProcessStartInfo needs to have the filename and arguments property set. Is there a way to mimic a true shell-like execute (like the one when you press WIN+R)?

Comment: What deficiencies are you finding with using `Process.Start`?

Comment: How about a batch file starting the process and using Process.Start to start the batch file?

Comment: The command line is coming from a configuration file and is provided as a whole. I just want to mimic the WIN+R functionality. I think even VBScript has a way to do what I need...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can launch `cmd.exe` with the full command-line you want to send as the arguments.

```
info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
info.Arguments = "app.exe /arg1:1 /arg2:true";
```

Comment: You'll probably need the /c switch to tell cmd.exe to execute app.exe.

Comment: I also thought about this solution but I don't like that the command window appears.

Answer (score 3):

ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute makes Process.Start behave exactly like the Shell:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx

Comment: I'm aware of this property but this still requires me to pass in the command and the arguments separately.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution I've been looking for: [Executing another program from C#, do I need to parse the "command line" from registry myself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560356/executing-another-program-from-c-do-i-need-to-parse-the-command-line-from-reg)

Thanks again for your help!