# How do I pass parameters in run-time compilation in c#, winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, codedom, runtime-compilation

I'm stuck on run-time compilation and CodeDom.
Here's a simplified example of what I have so far.

```
public static void Testing()
    {
        CodeDomProvider codeProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
        string Output = "Out.exe";

        System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();

        parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
        parameters.OutputAssembly = Output;
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Drawing.Dll");
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.Dll");
        parameters.CompilerOptions = "/t:winexe";

        string[] text = new string[] { @"C:\MyProject\Test.cs", @"C:\MyProject\Test.Designer.cs",
        @"C:\MyProject\Program.cs"};

        CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(parameters, text);

        Process.Start(Output);

    }
```

It works perfectly alright, and loads the Test form.

But! I need to pass a parameter to this Test form (a list of Panel controls) to populate the form.

How can I do this? Maybe, I am looking in the wrong direction, and it has to be done in a different way? 
Thanks a lot in advance!

**EDIT**
In the end, I give up on CodeDom and used [**Mono.Cecil**](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) instead, injecting .exe file with information from my main program.

Comment: Maybe you can pass that parameter as a command-line argument and handle it in the child app?

Comment: @khachik Thank you for your answer! Could you, please, provide more information on how to pass a parameter to command-line in dynamic compilation?

Comment: Can you please explain your requirement. I am not getting it clear.

Comment: @Subhash Lama Shortly, what I need to achieve is the following. The user should have the possibility to first populate a list of Panel controls with various stuff, and then create an .exe file which includes this Test form with Panels on it. So, I need to pass the list of Panels to the class, which is to be compiled on the fly.

Comment: You are *not* close.  Create a sample Winforms project first that does this.  Only then will you know what code to generate.

Comment: @Hans Passant I'm sorry, I'm stupid but I don't understand, what you mean by creating a sample winforms project that does this. Does what exactly? Because I have a project that allows the user to populate the panels. I need to provide them with possibility to click on the Finish button and get the .exe with all the info they entered.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is compiling an executable assembly then starting it in another process.

If you want to pass it information, [command line arguments are one option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807097/start-a-command-line-including-arguments-from-c). However, passing a .Net object on the command line will not work.

If you want to pass somthing managed you will have to use your new assembly with some [late binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484214/c-early-and-late-binding) and pass your object to the constructor perhaps, rather depends what the code you are compiling accepts, if you have that at design time ...

Are you re-writing Visual Studio?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This all seems a bit too complicated for such a simple thing that I'm trying to achieve. Above I tried to explain what I'm doing in my comment to Subhash Lama.